# Simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n - k}{k}x^k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n - k}{k}x^k$ into some easy to evaluate form, say something similar to $(x + a)^n$ or a single expression, but am having difficulty with it. I also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382826/sum-k-0-lfloor-fracn2-rfloor-binomn-kk-f-n1) previous answer, which shows that for $x = 1$, the sum is $F_n$, though it's hard to generalise the combinatorics argument... How should I generalise this?

Comment: There is a recurrence relation, see [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D%5Crfloor%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%20-%20k%7D%7Bk%7Dx%5Ek%24&p=1) results.

Comment: @BillyJoe The first two links seems to give wrong results but scrolling down further I found the correct one - $f(n) = 10f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)$. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$, let $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n - k}{k}x^k$, and let $A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$.  Then
\begin{align}
A(z) 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n - k}{k}x^k z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \sum_{n=2k}^\infty \binom{n - k}{k} z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k z^{2k} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n + k}{k} z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k z^{2k} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x z^2}{1-z}\right)^k \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x z^2/(1-z)} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z-x z^2}.
\end{align}
For $x=1$, this is well-known to be the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers.